# Difference between click_on and click_link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, poltergeist

I am writing request specs and I am using poltergeist-1.0.2 and capybara-1.1.2. I have the following code:

```
    login_as @user, 'Test1234!'
    click_on 'Virtual Terminal'
```

the login has flash message that shows to the user that he is successfully logged in. When I am using click_link, the spec fails because Capybara can't find element 'Virtual Terminal' but when I am using click_on everything passes. 'Virtual Terminal' is not a button, it is a link.

What is the difference between click_on and click_link.

Comment: Could you maybe give the html code of the page you are testing on?

Answer (score 8):

Click link uses a finder which specifies that you are looking for a link with the locator you provided and then does click on it as such:

```
def click_link(locator, options={})
  find(:link, locator, options).click
end
```

Click on instead uses a finder that specifies that it should be a link or a button as:

```
def click_link_or_button(locator, options={})
  find(:link_or_button, locator, options).click
end
alias_method :click_on, :click_link_or_button
```

Source: [Capybara actions](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb)

This leads us in turn to the selectors :link and :link_or_button and that is defined as follows:

```
Capybara.add_selector(:link_or_button) do
  label "link or button"
  xpath { |locator| XPath::HTML.link_or_button(locator) }
  filter(:disabled, :default => false) { |node, value| node.tag_name == "a" or not(value ^ node.disabled?) }
end

Capybara.add_selector(:link) do
  xpath { |locator| XPath::HTML.link(locator) }
  filter(:href) do |node, href|
    node.first(:xpath, XPath.axis(:self)[XPath.attr(:href).equals(href.to_s)])
  end
end
```

Source: [Capubara selectors](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L90)

The Xpath locators only differ in searching for link or link and button as shown in this sourcecode:

```
def link_or_button(locator)
  link(locator) + button(locator)
end

def link(locator)
  link = descendant(:a)[attr(:href)]
  link[attr(:id).equals(locator) | string.n.contains(locator) |  attr(:title).contains(locator) | descendant(:img)[attr(:alt).contains(locator)]]
end

def button(locator)
  button = descendant(:input)[attr(:type).one_of('submit', 'reset', 'image', 'button')][attr(:id).equals(locator) | attr(:value).contains(locator) | attr(:title).contains(locator)]
  button += descendant(:button)[attr(:id).equals(locator) | attr(:value).contains(locator) | string.n.contains(locator) | attr(:title).contains(locator)]
  button += descendant(:input)[attr(:type).equals('image')][attr(:alt).contains(locator)]
end
```

Source: [Xpath html](http://rdoc.info/github/jnicklas/xpath/XPath/HTML#link-instance_method)

As you can see the button locator actually finds a lot of different types which your link might fall under, if I had the html source code I could tell if it does or not.

Comment: So, even today, `click_on` will always utilize the default max wait time (not just `page.has_content?('my content')`