# Rspec with Capybara not finding link or any elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara

I am writing feature tests for my Rails 5 application. One feature is the ability to click a link with method POST.

```
visit "/admin/client_servers/#{client_server.id}"
click_on('Request Review From Application Owner')
```

I receive the error "Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find link or button 'Request Review From Application Owner'"

Just experimenting, I check to see if the test can find any element I know is on the screen. I have one container div with a class of 'description' and the test is unable to find the element.

The previous test passes

```
  visit "/admin/client_servers/#{client_server.id}"
  expect(page).to have_text("Request Review From Application Owner")
```

So I know the text I want to click on appears on the page.
My html is setup:

```
<div class="mark-ready-btn server-button" id="overall-tab" data-param="overall">
    <%=link_to admin_client_servers_update_review_status_path(status: 1, id: @server.id), class: "request-review-btn", method: 'POST' do%>
      <div class="server-mark-ready" id="overall-tab" data-param="overall">
        Request Review From Application Owner
      </div>
    <%end%>
</div>
```

I've checked but the test is unable to find the css tags '.mark-ready-btn server-button', '.request-review-btn', or '.server-mark-ready'. I've searched this problem online and looked into Capybara and Rspec documentation. Is there something I'm missing or a improper syntax I've written in the test? I'd appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: Have you tried `click_link` instead of `click_on`? See this answer for detailed explaination https://stackoverflow.com/a/17564749/1202324 .
Since you have a `div` inside of your `a` capybara could be confused and does not see it as a link or button.

Comment: What version of Capybara are you using?  What driver are you using?  Is your document being served with the HTML5 doctype or is it being served as HTML4 ? Also, please look at `page.html` and find the relevant part of the actual HTML that is being processed and add that to your question.

Comment: try to find the `id=overall-tab` you have your div
`find("#overall-tab").click`

Answer (score 1):

You can try -

```
within ".mark-ready-btn.server-button" do
  click_on ".server-mark-ready"
end
```

Or you can use "find"

```
find('.server-mark-ready').click
```

Answer (score 0):

If Capybara can't find link or button, generally means that there is no link or button. You will have to use 'click' method.

From your html example, this should work

```
1.first('.server-mark-ready).click
2.page.all('.server-mark-ready)[#].click (in case there is more than one div that has that class)
```

Answer (score 0):

`find("#overall-tab").click` should do the work

Or if you really want to click on specific text try:

`find('div', text: 'Request Review From Application Owner').click`